# Flex SWF Gradient Background

Tags: apache-flex, background

Every time I compile a MXML file, I get a SWF file. When I load the SWF file to the browser, all the space outside the SWF file is this gray gradient.

I want to change the color, or make it disappear entirely, however, when I search for "Flex background color" I get information to do other things.

How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to thr compiler arguments:

```
-default-background-color #222222
```

Where color is the color you like.

To change background color of SWF itself change values of `Application` tag. For MX `Application` refer to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html) and take a look at `backgroundGradientAlphas` and `backgroundGradientColors` styles.

For Spark `Application` documentation is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html).

Comment: It did not change the gray gradient outside the SWF file.

Comment: Ah. As far as it is a gradient it is a part of SWF. You can make sure by right click on gradient and see `About Flash Player` in context menu. Right?

Comment: I see the flash player context menu. However, I never set anything in the MXML for that gray gradient. It must be a default.

Comment: I've added information about adjucting `Application` background.